Next-Auth always true call of signIn method
I've been following a YouTube tutorial on how to implement next-auth into a nextjs JavaScript project. This is the video in question if it helps .
I've been following it toughly and had no mayor problems until the last part, of using the useSession to verify if someone logged in. I think I copied the code exactly as he has it, but I still get a problem that basically, no matter what I send as email and password, it always returns true and no errors, even if they are absolutely not correct.
This is the page I've used as a login page:
'use client'
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { redirect, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function LoginPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const loginUser = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Entered login user");
        console.log(data);
    
        const result = await signIn("credentials", {
            ...data,
            redirect: false,
        });
    
        if (result.error) {
            // Handle sign-in error
            console.error(result.error);
        } else {
            console.log("Sign-in successful")
            console.log(result)
            // Sign-in successful, redirect to the dashboard
            //router.push('/dashboard');
        }
    }
...

and this is my api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js file:
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        // Check if email and password are provided
        if (!credentials.email || !credentials.password) {
          return null;
        }

        // Check if the email exists
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: { email: credentials.email }
        });

        // If email doesn't exist, return null
        if (!user) {
          return null;
        }

        // Check if the password is correct
        const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        // If passwords don't match, return null
        if (!passwordsMatch) {
          return null;
        }

        // Return user if email and password are valid
        return user;
      }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


The problem is, you can't call all the configurations in the route:
api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

In this route all do you need is export this: export { GET, POST } from '@/auth';
and all the code it's should be in the root of your app with name "auth.js" /src/auth.js and put there all the code of your provider, like this:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas";

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: "Credentials",

      async authorize(credentials) {
        const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);

        if (validatedFields.success) {
           // in this case I'm use Zod to validate all my credentials, if my credentials are correct (username, password), in this part I put all my logic to fetch the user, in your case in your database Prisma and then I return the user.
            
           return user;
          }

        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
});

and the credentials from my form is coming to the server action in my case:
    'use server';
import { z } from 'zod';
import { LoginSchema } from '@/schemas';
import { signIn } from '@/auth';
import { AuthError } from 'next-auth';
import { DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT } from '@/routes';

export const login = async (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
  const validateFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(values);

  if (!validateFields.success) {
    return { error: 'Invalid fields' };
  }

  const { username, password } = validateFields.data;

  try {
    await signIn('credentials', {
      username,
      password,
      redirectTo: DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle error
    if (e instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (e.type) {
        case 'CredentialsSignin':
          return { error: 'Invalid Credentials' };
        default:
          return { error: 'An error occurred' };
      }
    }
    throw e;
  }
};

next-auth provide you tools that you can use to handler errors and the signIn.
(And the best way to me handle the protected routes is through the middleware)
You can consult the documentation: https://authjs.dev/
This is the code that I use, I hope this code help you to fix your error.
